# How can I convert a large data table (with about 1,500 columns) from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access-2013

Apologies but this is my first question and I simply cannot see a link to upload excel files. I have also searched the help articles and couldn't find instructions. Can anyone advise ?

I have a table of data in Excel with around 1,500 columns and around the same number of rows and I'd like to transfer the data into Access for ease of manipulation. Obviously I cannot reference the table directly from within Access because it exceeds Access's column limit. Unfortunately the source data needs to stay in Excel because it's the output of a number of other files/models which write directly into Excel.

A complicating factor is the number of records. If I convert the data into row format (from row and column format) to upload into access there will be around 2.25 million rows i.e. too large for a single Excel worksheet. Hence I have to split the data across multiple Excel worksheets then upload into access one by one. Obviously this is a laborious process.

To be specific, my data looks like this:

```
    D1  D1  D1  D2  D2  D2  D3  D3  D3
    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q1  Q2  Q3

S1  Q1  0.76    0.40    0.44    0.60    0.68    0.35    0.80    0.75    0.37 
S1  Q2  0.33    0.92    0.01    0.68    0.86    0.43    0.27    0.54    0.20 
S1  Q3  0.40    0.10    0.71    0.86    0.07    0.44    0.55    0.77    0.41 
S2  Q1  0.15    0.34    0.10    0.32    0.39    0.47    0.18    1.00    0.37 
S2  Q2  0.12    0.31    0.58    0.68    0.06    0.21    0.73    0.66    0.48 
S2  Q3  0.71    0.51    1.00    0.39    0.09    0.20    0.72    0.03    0.74 
S3  Q1  0.71    0.10    0.01    0.30    0.12    0.14    0.69    0.84    0.07 
S3  Q2  0.21    0.51    0.09    0.81    0.01    0.36    0.94    0.14    0.57 
S3  Q3  0.90    0.28    0.66    0.45    0.19    0.59    0.17    0.14    0.73
```

And I would like to covert to the following format

```
S1  Q1  D1  Q1  0.76
S1  Q1  D1  Q2  0.40
S1  Q1  D1  Q3  0.44
```

etc

Can anyone suggest a way of quickly converting the data into into a single file for fast upload into Access?

Any tips/techniques will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

DG.

Comment: Can you perhaps upload some sample data in an Excel file with explanation as to current data and expected end result? I expect PowerQuery would be the way to tranform the data into a shape that can be used. ALso, you don't make clear why you want to use Access.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the data as code to make it readable. And explain the connection between the first 2 rows and the rest.

Comment: I made a tentative edit to your data list. But it is completely unclear how your result is created - how do the first two rows connect to the rest?

Comment: You could use this to show your table(s): http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Excel can't hold 2.25 million rows then convert it to csv file.. A small VBA code will do...

Comment: Thank you Andre for the edit. The data represent costs. The first 2 rows represent customers (D1, D2 etc) and a quality of product they order (Q1, Q2 etc). The first 2 columns represent a potential warehouse to supply them from (S1, S2 etc) and a quality of product to supply (Q1, Q2 etc). I would like to import the data to Access primarily because I want to perform further calculations and Excel is struggling to cope.

Comment: Huy Pham, thanks for your comment. Would you recommend writing code to deposit the data directly in Access, or create another file type (such as CSV) for Access to link to (via Access's import data functions)?